# Change return type dynamically?

Tags: c

Let's say I have this method:

```
matrix* multiply(smatrix *sm, matrix *m){
```

Even if it return `matrix *` I want to dynamically change its return type. Can I set the return type as `void *` and cast it later?

Comment: You need to give an actual code example of what it is that you are proposing to do

Comment: Yes, you can. Didn't you try?

Comment: Is just because you want to hand in matrices of different sizes, or do you have a deeper typing problem, here?

Comment: How would you know what type to cast it to later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare **void* multiply(smatrix *sm, matrix *m)**
and then typecast the return type later

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can return a void* pointer and cast it into anything you would like. Just make sure you are returning what you expect otherwise you could access the wrong memory.

It may be bad to design the code this way as it can get ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the cast in the call to the function.

```
struct wibble
  *w;

w = (struct wibble *)( multiply(sm, m) );
```

BTW, you might want to consider not typedef'ing matrix.  I imagine it's a struct, so it has a type already.  You increase the complexity of the code with the typedef; and that's all you get for it.

Comment: If the function returns a `void*` the cast is not needed ... and if it doesn't the cast is probably wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is already mentioned - return type `(void*)`. However i want to mention another not discussed option here-
make return type `Union`, like so:

```
typedef union {
    int scalar;
    int* vector;
    int** matrix;
} custom_type;


custom_type* myFunction() {
// todo
}
```

`Union` is much like `Struct` except that `Union` members shares same memory, so only one member of all union members can be set/used at a time. But be careful - you must clearly know what to expect from function in exact situation (But i think the same warning applies to `void*` case).

cheers!

Comment: Why does the union have a typedef?  when someone else reads the code, they will need to see what the underlying type is to be able to understand the code.  The typedef is obscuring the code.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use typedef with union/struct, because it lets to shorten variable declarations. I.E. i prefer to write shorter declaration `MyType var;` instead of `struct MyType var;`. But it's just my personal coding style, I by no means don't force to use it by somebody else...

Comment: Nice for you.  Sucks for everyone who reads your code.  I think a crucial part of being a good programmer is making code which is understandable by others.

Comment: @Blank Xavier: speak for you. I don't have trouble reading code with typedef'd data, it usually won't take more than 10 secs to look at the definition, and I find it more readable instead of less. Generalizations, in general, suck.

Comment: @Jucao: I came to my current view after working for 18 months with a one million line codebase, where most everything was typedefed and quite a lot of them were used in ways which depended fully on what the actual underlying type really was.  Most bad practises are entirely manageable in tiny or small code bases, or in code managed by the original author.